# How to validate fields of an object in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Following is a sample class:-

```
public class Response {

  private String hash;
  private Integer count;
  private Optional<String> name = Optional.empty();

  // getters and setters
}
```

Now in the JSP file, I can access the fields, something like:-

```
<c:forEach var="rr" items="${data}">
  ${rr.hash}
  ...
</c:forEach>
```

My question is, how will I come to know in the JSP file if the value for that field exists? There is a `name` field which is optional. If for an instance, I have not set it's value, then how can I know this is the JSP file?